# Android(Linux) uptime using CLOCK_MONOTONIC

Tags: android, linux, time, linux-kernel

According to [Android Developer Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29) `uptimeMillis()` returns the number of milliseconds since boot, **not counting time spent in deep sleep**. I checked the implementation of 
 `uptimeMillis()` in my code and it is roughly like this-

```
struct timespec t;
t.tv_sec = t.tv_nsec = 0;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t);
return (int64_t)(t.tv_sec)*1000000000LL + t.tv_nsec;
```

As far as I know `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` counts from some **unspecified point** linearly including sleep time.

Here are my doubts-

1. If `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` includes sleep time, how come  `uptimeMillis()` doesn't take it into account? If my understanding is wrong and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` doesn't take sleep into account, then what should I use to get system uptime including sleep?
2. What is deep sleep? Is the CPU idling referred as deep sleep?
3. What is the value of **unspecified point** in Linux? Can you kindly point out in code where this clock is started?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. CLOCK_MONOTONIC stops when the system is suspended. Some people felt this was a mistake, and subsequently there have been patches for adding a CLOCK_BOOTTIME clock: https://lwn.net/Articles/428176/  . <strike>I don't know if these patches have yet been included in the mainline kernel.</strike> *CLOCK_BOOTTIME is in ndk-9c - it only took 2,5 years ;)* –  Wojciech
2. Suspend, I guess.
3. IIRC some fixed time before boot. You'll find the exact value if you dig into the kernel source. Then again, the entire point about it being **unspecified** is that it could change at any point, so relying on it seems unwise to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot janneb!! It was quite helpful. But can you elaborate on suspend? By suspend, do you mean the process is suspended or the entire CPU is idling?

Comment: @Pavan: Suspend, as in the entire system is suspended.

Comment: Thanks again! I checked in 2.6.35. `CLOCK_BOOTTIME` isn't there yet! But still `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` is able to do it! Any idea of how's it doing?

Comment: @Pavan: The "Realtime" in the method name suggests it's a realtime clock, don't you think? Wrt the CLOCK_BOOTTIME, the patch I linked to was posted in February 2011, whereas 2.6.35 was released in August 2010, so it's not surprising you won't find it there..

Comment: CLOCK_BOOTTIME is in ndk-9c - it only took 2,5 years ;)